# Polymorph(?) async method

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have the following code in my ASP.Net MVC Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetAnimals()
{
    List<Dog> dogs = GetDogs("api/dogs).Result;
    List<Cat> dogs = GetCats("api/cats).Result;
    List<Horse> dogs = GetCats("api/cats).Result;
...
...
}


private async Task<List<Dog>> GetDogs(string requestUri)
{
    String ret = "";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://theservice.com/");
    var response = client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ret = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Dog>>();
    }
    else
    { }
    return ret;
}

private async Task<List<Cat>> GetCats(string requestUri)
{
    String ret = "";
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://theservice.com/");
    var response = client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ret = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Cat>>();
    }
    else
    { }
    return ret;
}
```

How can I avoid rerwriting the Get-method over and over again, depending on the return type. There must be a smart way!

Comment: As a side note, try to avoid directly accessing the .Result property of a Task. This is a blocking operation. Instead, use await also for the client.GetAsync method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use generics:

```
private async Task<List<T>> GetItems<T>(string requestUri)
{
    String ret = "";
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://theservice.com/");
    var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ret = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<T>>();
    }
    else
    { }
    return ret;
}
```

You can use it within your `GetDogs`/`GetCats` methods:

```
private async Task<List<Dog>> GetDogs(string requestUri)
{
    return GetItems<Dog>(requestUri);
}
```

Or directly as `GetItems<ClassName>(requestUri)`.